# Like command SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-like

I'm trying to construct an SQL query that looks for multiple different things I think the like command is the best way to achieve this

the line in the query is:

`where *field* like 'AB%'` it lists all the instaces in the table where it begins AB....

when i try and add multiple instances though i get an error message, I want to do something like the following:

```
where *field* like ('AB%','CD%','EF%')
```

So I get the fields for specific entries that start with the list of text I have provided

Could somebody help me with this please?

Comment: Paste some actual SQL code please, then it will be easier for us to help you (edit your original post and paste it in there).

Comment: Most databases have support for Regular Expressions. What database engine are you using?

Answer (score 5):

You want `OR`

```
WHERE field LIKE 'AB%' 
   OR field LIKE 'CD%'
   OR field LIKE 'EF%'
```

If you are using other `WHERE` clause criteria, you'll need to bracket off the OR clauses using parenthesis.

Hope it helps...

**EDIT:**

After your comment, you could try using [regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_regexp.htm), especially [REGEXP_LIKE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm) in your `WHERE` clause.

Something along the lines of (untested):

```
SELECT *
  FROM table
 WHERE regexp_like(field, '^(AB|CD|EF).*$')
```

Comment: If have over 100 "like" examples is there a more effecient way?

Comment: Yes, you could use regular expressions: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_regexp.htm

Comment: Please define "more efficient".  If you're running a query with more than one hundred LIKE filters it seems unlikely that query performance is top of your mind.  So presumably you mean "a solution which requires less typing"?

Comment: I agree with @APC, if you are trying to find results from over 100 discrete patterns, you might want to consider whether there is a better way of achieving your goals. Perhaps if you state your data and the goal you are trying to satisfy someone on here might be able to give you a "more efficient" method for achieving it.

Answer (score 1):

`WHERE *field* LIKE 'AB%' OR *field* LIKE 'CD%' OR *field* LIKE 'EF%'`

Comment: If have over 100 "like" examples is there a more effecient way?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Oracle, you can write:

```
where regexp_like(t1, '^AB|^CD|^EF')
```

etc.

Comment: my apologies, I tested it and mucked up my example code. It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the instr function.  If it finds the substring you want at the first position of the string, it would return 1:

```
where instr(field,'AB') = 1
OR instr(field,'CD') = 1
OR instr(field,'ED') = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do it with single string, try to use REGEXP:

```
WHERE *field* REGEXP 'AB(.*)|CD(.*)|EF(.*)'
```

Comment: this is not valid Oracle syntax.